# Google Spreadsheet, how to grab row from other sheet using vlookup?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I got two sheets in my google spreadsheet:

- MC
- Items (rather big)

In "MC i got a column with different Item Names.
I need to find the matching ID from sheet "Items".
Created a vlookup for it, but cant get it to work - everything looks okay to me.

Link to sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yif8Cf1g1pPI38YFCffDKQ1tE-08SWPSfRAv-TdWXTw/edit?usp=sharing

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Items!$A$2:B,2,false)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
={"id"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {Items!B:B, Items!A:A}, 2, 0)))}
```

[image]